# Getting guest customer DOB in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, customer, guest-checkout

How can I get the date of birth of a guest customer? Where is this information in the database?

Answer (score 2):

If you have **Order object** then you can get ***Guest Customer dob*** from `getCustomerDob()`.

In *magento database*  you can get guest customer dob from `sales_flat_order` table's `customer_dob` column.

Suppose,you have order then you can get guest customer dob from

```
$OrderObject = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load('Order_Id');
$DOb         = $OrderObject->getCustomerDob(); // yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
```

Comment: I tried your code in a order confirmation email template and got an error. Probably not the correct place for this code. After thinking it over I decided to create accounts for all customers because not doing so was going to require a lot of customizations. Now I just generate and capture the customer's password in hidden fields in the checkout. Much easier it seems. So I can't exactly say your code is the answer. Thanks thou!